# Changing Visibility of NSbox Objective C

Tags: cocoa, nsbox

How can I change a `NSBox` to `isHidden:YES|NO` programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any subclass of NSView responds to the [`setHidden:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSView) method, so to change it simply call

```
[box setHidden:YES];
```

Comment: I get that, but how to call the box name from the interface. I tried many different ways.

Comment: Got it, thanks. There was another error with the outlet that I found.